# Is there any way to pass variable number of images to a CNN

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a video classification task.
I want to fetch N frames and pass it to my CNN. N depends on the size of video. If i have a video of 5 min i may have 200 frames, I will have more frames & if I have a video of less then a min, I may have 34-5 frames. How to make an NN that accepts variable number of images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the term 'batches'. Look up tensorflow/pytorch's tutorial for i. You don't need to send a variable number, just image width, height and channel information.